# DataExplorer package installation

Tags: macos, r, anaconda, rstudio

I'm unable to install the DataExplorer R package. I'm using RStudio anaconda distribution with R version 3.5.1 on my mac os x 10.13.6. In RStudio I've tried:

install.packages("dataexplorer", repos="https://r.anaconda.org/silviage")
which returns:
Warning in install.packages:
package 'dataexplorer' is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Installation from CRAN returns:
Warning in install.packages:
installation of package 'DataExplorer' had a non-zero exit status

using remotes package and the following
devtools::install_github("boxuancui/DataExplorer")
begins installation then an RStudio popup reads 'Install Build Tools Building R package from source requires installation of additional build tools. Do you want to install the additional tools now?'to which I click 'yes' and I install the tools but the message keeps poping up and R Console finally says 'Installation failed: Command failed (1)'

Has anyone successfully installed DataExplorer with anaconda on a mac?

If I'm unable to install DataExplorer given my setup are there any recommendations on similar EDA R packages.

Comment: What specific problem are you having? Are you getting any error messages? "It's not possible" is not a proper error description. Please [edit] and update your post.

Comment: updated the message with details of the errors I'm getting